# TCL-Getting Log of Exec'd Process

Tags: tcl

Currently I am firing following command

```
set pid [exec make &]

set term_id [wait pid]
```

**First command** will execute makefile inside TCL and **Second Command** will wait for first command's makefile operation to complete. **First command** displays all logs of makefile on stdout. Is it possible to store all logs in variable or file when "&" is given in the last argument of exec using redirection or any other method?

If "&" is not given then we can take the output using,

```
set log [exec make]
```

But if "&" is given then command will return process id,

```
set pid [exec make &]
```

So is it possible stop the `stdout` logs and put them in variable?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Tcl 8.6, you can capture the output using:

```
lassign [chan pipe] reader writer
set pid [exec make >@$writer &]
close $writer
```

Don't forget to read from the `$reader` or the subprocess will stall. Be aware that when used in this way, the output will be delivered fully-buffered, though this is more important when doing interactive work. If you want the output echoed to standard out as well, you will need to make your script do that. Here's a simple reader handler.

```
while {[gets $reader line] >= 0} {
    lappend log $line
    puts $line
}
close $reader
```

---

Before Tcl 8.6, your best bet would be to create a subprocess command pipeline:

```
set reader [open |make]
```

If you need the PID, this can become a bit more complicated:

```
set reader [open |[list /bin/sh -c {echo $$; exec make}]]
set pid [gets $reader]
```

Yes, that's pretty ugly…

---

[EDIT]: You're using Tk, in Tcl 8.5 (so you need the `open |…` pipeline form from above), and so you want to keep the event loop going. That's fine. That's exactly what `fileevent` is for, but you *have to think asynchronously*.

```
# This code assumes that you've opened the pipeline already
fileevent $reader readable [list ReadALine $reader]
proc ReadALine {channel} {
    if {[gets $channel line] >= 0} {
        HandleLine $line
    } else {
        # No line could be read; must be at the end
        close $channel
    }
}
proc HandleLine {line} {
    global log
    lappend log $line;     # Or insert it into the GUI or whatever
    puts $line
}
```

This example does *not* use non-blocking I/O. That *might* cause an issue, but probably won't. If it does cause a problem, use this:

```
fconfigure $reader -blocking 0
fileevent $reader readable [list ReadALine $reader]
proc ReadALine {channel} {
    if {[gets $channel line] >= 0} {
        HandleLine $line
    } elseif {[eof $channel]} {
        close $channel
    }
}
proc HandleLine {line} {
    global log
    lappend log $line
    puts $line
}
```

More complex and versatile versions are possible, but they're only really necessary once you're dealing with untrusted channels (e.g., public server sockets).

---

If you'd been using 8.6, you could have used coroutines to make this code look more similar to the straight-line code I used earlier, but they're a feature that is strictly 8.6 (and later, once we do later versions) only as they depend on the stack-free execution engine.

Comment: let me rephrase my question, I am using 8.5... My make operation is producing lots of logs on stdout and as well as displays gui.. Is it possible to transfer that on variable? and without "&" my logs and GUI is not visible in exec?

Comment: With Tcl 8.5 you could still use Donal's first solution if you also have the TclX extension (or can install it) but substituting [the TclX pipe command](http://wiki.tcl.tk/2033) for the `chan pipe` which is built-in to Tcl 8.6.

Comment: @AxT_8041 Check out my extended version of the answer. It _should_ cover everything you need.